# Is the Uncertainty Principle really correct?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I know that the Principle must be correct, but in my book, an intuitive explanation was given. It  said that

> As we throw a photon of wavelength similar to the size of electrons, we determine it's position but we lost the information about momentum.

Now, what's different. I mean, even if we consider the Bohr's theory, we can say that as the photon strikes to an electron, it excites and we cannot say for sure in which direction it will go (at least assume it).

So my point is

> Is it necessary to say that we cannot determine the exact position and momentum of the electron at any instant. Rather, we should say that we cannot know it at the time of measurement, but at any other time, we can correctly predict it on the basis of the formulas that we have?

Seeing the basis of my understanding of it, please explain in that terms only?

Comment: This may help [Why is it impossible to measure position and momentum at the same time with arbitrary precision?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/599980/37364)

Comment: And maybe this [Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622155/37364)

Comment: well… maybe you should look up other explanations in alternate sources as the one from your text seems rather unclear.